# Normalising vhost name from varnish for statsd

Tags: varnish, logstash, statsd

### The setup

I am collecting statistics from *Varnish* with *Logstash*, which is configured to increment *statsd* counters based on the vhost in the server logs and the result code.  I also have *carbon* creating *whisper* archives for *graphite*.

I'm reading logs from *varnishncsa* which is configured to add vhost and request disposition to the standard logs:

```
VARNISHNCSA_LOG_FORMAT="%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %{Host}i %{Varnish:hitmiss}x"
```

My logstash shipper config looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log"
    type => varnish
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    type => varnish
    pattern => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} %{NOTSPACE:vhost} %{WORD:varnish_handling}"
    pattern => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
  }

  mutate {
    rename => [ 'response', 'status' ]
  }
}

output {
  statsd {
    type => varnish
    host => "my-statsd-host"
    port => 8125
    sender => "%{@fields.vhost}"
    increment => "varnish.response.%{@fields.status}"
    increment => "varnish.handling.%{@fields.varnish_handling}"
  }
}
```

### The problem

Hundreds of distinct counters are being created by *carbon* due to variations in the domain entered into users' browsers.  So, for example, I have

```
www_mywebsite_com
WWW_MyWebsite_Com
www_mywebsite_net    <-- an alias
...etc...
```

Obviously these are then missed by my graphs, which only look at statistics under the vhost's canonical name.

What I'd like is for some canonicalising process to happen beforehand.  I can write a script to take a 'raw' domain and spit out a 'real' vhost name, but I'm not sure how to integrate that.  Do I put it in the logstash config, or in statsd, or carbon?  Could I do something with carbon's storage aggregation feature?

**Update**:  I've worked around the worst cases by running carbon's aggregator daemon in front of the cache, and adding rules to `rewrite-rules.conf`.  However, there's very little documentation for that file, and I can't do more powerful things like smash everything down to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

you can lowercase a field with the mutate filter:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "fieldname" ]
  }
}
```

[Logstash 1.1.13 Docs](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.13/filters/mutate#setting_lowercase)

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: Thanks for that -- that takes care of instances where the case is the only problem.  However I'd also like to normalise aliases of vhosts (see third line in my example).